# How can I stop and start EC2 automatically, when it not responding on http

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have an EC2 with the HTTP server; I want to stop and start it automatically when it was not responding on HTTP port after 2 minutes.

**What is the best way to implement on AWS without using the scale group and elastic load balancer(ELB).**

As I mentioned before, I don't need to create the new instance, just stop and start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First instead of stopping and starting instance considering restarting service with help of monit or another monitoring service because restarting instance will take time and not a good idea.
- But if you are worried about instance going down scenarios, you can configure auto healing(https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-recovery-for-amazon-ec2/).
- Another custom way of doing would be, inside instance do a simple hello check using curl and store the response log and schedule it in a cron, Sync the log to cloudwatch and in cloudwatch you can plot metric using logs, and configure alarm if the metric count goes below a threshold for 2 mins, you can write lambda function to restart the instance, and associate the lambda to the alarm.(https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/). Since you have mentioned you are having one instance this approach will work, if you have more than  one instance you need to handle namespace, But again restarting instance is a not a good idea.

Comment: The second one is not working because when HTTP was not working, the instance status is OK on the EC2 dashboard. Could you explain the third option?

Comment: @RezaMousavi, I have updated the answer with further details but the 3rd approach is not recommended :).

Comment: as I mentioned before, the second option not working, because when HTTP was not working, the instance status is OK on the EC2 dashboard

Comment: What about having a monit, doing a restart of http server when it's not responding

Answer (score 1):

I am using Route53 healthcheck which, when triggered, sends notification to SNS topic that triggers Lambda function that reboots the server.